# django 1.11 Cannot extend templates recursively when using non-recursive template loaders

Tags: python, django, templates, loader, django-middleware

I have django 1.11.2 and I instaled django-mobile=0.7.0.

When I want to go to admin panel I recive an error:

```
ExtendsError at /admin/
Cannot extend templates recursively when using non-recursive template loaders
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: ExtendsError
Exception Value:    
Cannot extend templates recursively when using non-recursive template loaders
```

I recive an error in first line `{% extends "admin/base.html" %}`

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load admin_static %}{% load suit_tags %}

{% block branding %} {% endblock branding %}
```

My templates settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django_mobile.context_processors.flavour',
            ],
            'loaders': (
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
                'django_mobile.loader.Loader',
            ),
            'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
]
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['loaders']
```

Middleware classes:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django_mobile.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
    'django_mobile.middleware.SetFlavourMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: django-mobile 0.7 was released nearly two years ago. I don't think you can expect it to work with Django 1.11, which was released a year later.

Answer (score 0):

The [installation instructions](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile/blob/master/README.rst) in the readme say that `django_mobile.loader.Loader` should be the **first** item in `loaders`, e.g.:

```
'loaders': (
    'django_mobile.loader.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
),
```

At the moment, you have it at the end, so Django will try to use other loaders first.